# Laravel pass param url id to controller function

Tags: laravel

I have a page with data/information on it with a download button that converts my page to pdf. Now, the download button is my problem with how I can do it.

My current page URL.

```
Route::get('/inventory/{id}', function ($id) {
    $inventory = Inventory::find($id);
    return view('layouts._inventory-template', ['inventory' => $inventory])
});
```

My button in the view

```
<a href="{{ action('ClientController@viewPdf', ['id' => $request()->route('id')]) }}" class="button button-secondary"><span></span>PDF</a>
```

Function in ClientController

```
public function viewPdf($id)
{
    $inventory = Inventory::find($id);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts._inventory-template');
    return $pdf->download('inventory.pdf');
}
```

Question: How I can implement the logic of PDF download button in the view page?

Comment: I don't get with what you want exactly. Please make your question clearly!

Comment: How I can implement the logic of PDF download button in the view page?

Answer (score 0):

In your router:

```
Route::get('/viewPdf/{id}', 'ClientController@viewPdf');
```

You can simple call your route in href:

```
<a href="/viewPDF/{{ $id }}" class="button button-secondary"><span></span>PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
Route::get('/inventory/{id}', 'ClientController@downloadPdf')->name('download-pdf');
```

ClientController

```
public function downloadPdf()
{
  $inventory = Inventory::find($id);
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts._inventory-template', $inventory);
  return $pdf->download('inventory.pdf');
}
```

Button

```
<a href="{{ route('download-pdf', Auth::user()->id) }}" title="">Download<i class="la la-download"></i></a>
```

Note: change **Auth::user()->id** in the button if ever you want something else

Answer (score 0):

Simply add download property in a tag

```
<a href="{{ action('ClientController@viewPdf', ['id' => $request()->route('id')]) }}" class="button button-secondary" download><span></span>PDF</a>
```